# I am getting error "A fatal error occurred at transformation [SQL]" while using sql transfrmation in informaticao

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am getting error

```
Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
ERROR   2/17/2017 12:30:46 AM   CAPPRD_NODE_01  TRANSF_1_1_1    TM_6085 A fatal error occurred at  transformation [SQL], and the session is terminating.
```

while using sql transformation in informatica. The source file is a flat file created in informatica itself and even target table is flat file. But at the end the session is aborted with error

```
Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
ERROR   2/17/2017 12:30:46 AM   CAPPRD_NODE_01  WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8170    Writer run terminated: Abort Session request received from the DTM
```

Can someone help me with this issue.

**Please find the logs details**

```
TM_6187 Session target-based commit interval is [10000].
TM_6307 DTM error log disabled. 
TE_7022 TShmWriter: Initialized
TM_6007 DTM initialized successfully for session [s_m_table_test]
PETL_24033  All DTM Connection Info: [<NONE>].
PETL_24004  PETL_24004 Starting pre-session tasks. : (Thu Feb 16 23:47:02 2017)
PETL_24027  PETL_24027 Pre-session task completed successfully. : (Thu Feb 16 23:47:02 2017)
PETL_24006  Starting data movement.
TM_6660 Total Buffer Pool size is 1219648 bytes and Block size is 65536 bytes.
DBG_21437   Reader: Source is a file-based source.
FR_3118 source [SQ_table] code page: [7-bit ASCII]
FR_3071 Maximum Line sequential buffer length is 1026.
BLKR_16003  Initialization completed successfully.
WRT_8124    Target Table target_table :Writing output to: *************
WRT_8222    Target file ****************** code page: [MS Windows Latin 1 (ANSI), superset of Latin1]
WRT_8270    Target connection group #1 consists of target(s) [target_table]
WRT_8003    Writer initialization complete.
BLKR_16007  Reader run started.
WRT_8005    Writer run started.
WRT_8158    

*START LOAD SESSION*

Load Start Time: Thu Feb 16 23:47:03 2017

Target tables:

target_table


DBG_21430   DBG_21430 Reading data from input source file ***************** : (Thu Feb 16 23:47:03 2017)
BLKR_16019  Read [1] rows, read [0] error rows for source table [table] instance name [table]
BLKR_16008  Reader run completed.
pmsql_50059 [ERROR] Script processing failed with the following error:
  Script File Name: XXXXXX; CREATE TABLE YYYY  ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object  Database driver error... Function Name : executeDirect SQL Stmt : CREATE TABLE *******************Oracle Fatal Error Database driver error... Function Name : ExecuteDirect  Oracle Fatal Error .
pmsql_50069 [INFO] The last query script file to run was: 
************* database [oracle], user [X], connect string [Y].
TM_6085 A fatal error occurred at  transformation [SQL], and the session is terminating. 
TM_6085 A fatal error occurred at  transformation [SQ_table], and the session is terminating. 
TM_6085 A fatal error occurred at  transformation [SQ_table], and the session is terminating. 
TM_6085 A fatal error occurred at  transformation [SQ_table], and the session is terminating. 
    DBG_21511   TE: Fatal Transformation Error.
WRT_8167    Start loading table [target_table] at: Thu Feb 16 23:47:03 2017
WRT_8333    Rolling back all the targets due to fatal session error.
WRT_8170    Writer run terminated: Abort Session request received from the DTM
WRT_8168    End loading table [target_table] at: Thu Feb 16 23:47:03 2017
WRT_8035    Load complete time: Thu Feb 16 23:47:03 2017

LOAD SUMMARY

WRT_8036 Target: target_table (Instance Name: [target_table])
WRT_8044 No data loaded for this target


WRT_8043    END LOAD SESSION
INFO    2/17/2017 10:17:03 AM   CAPPRD_NODE_01  MANAGER PETL_24031  
Y RUN INFO FOR TGT LOAD ORDER GROUP [1], CONCURRENT SET [1] Y
Thread [READER_1_1_1] created for [the read stage] of partition point [SQ_table] has completed. The total run time was insufficient for any meaningful statistics.
Thread [TRANSF_1_1_1] created for [the transformation stage] of partition point [SQ_table] has completed. The total run time was insufficient for any meaningful statistics.
Thread [WRITER_1_*_1] created for [the write stage] of partition point [target_table] has completed. The total run time was insufficient for any meaningful statistics.

PETL_24005 Starting post-session tasks. : (Thu Feb 16 23:47:03 2017)
PETL_24029  PETL_24029 Post-session task completed successfully. : (Thu Feb 16 23:47:03 2017)
MAPPING TM_6018 The session completed with [0] row transformation errors. 
MANAGER PETL_24002  Parallel Pipeline Engine finished.
PETL_24013  Session run completed with failure.
TM_6022 

SESSION LOAD SUMMARY

TM_6252 Source Load Summary.
CMN_1740    Table: [SQ_table] (Instance Name: [SQ_table])
     Output Rows [1], Affected Rows [1], Applied Rows [1], Rejected Rows [0]
TM_6253 Target Load Summary.
CMN_1740    Table: [target_table] (Instance Name: [target_table])
     Output Rows [0], Affected Rows [0], Applied Rows [0], Rejected Rows [0]
TM_6023   

TM_6020 Session [s_m_table_test] completed at [Thu Feb 16 23:47:03 2017].
```

*I tried editing logs to display properly but didn't go well i guess..*

Answer (score 0):

Easy one I guess... the CREATE TABLE statement your SQL transformation runs is trying to create a table that already exists in that database (per the error message ORA-00955). Go run a select * from that table to confirm this, why would you create the table every time the mapping runs? Or does it run only once